# I can't use mockito to replace the method call in SpringBatch

Tags: mockito, spring-batch

I'm trying to use mockito to replace the method call in SpringBatch. The code is greatly simplified and removed unnecessary to reduce it, if something is missing, write, I will add.

Spring Batch Settings File

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ListBatchConfig {
    @Bean
    public Job jobListBath(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                            StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                            ItemReader<Student> itemReaderListBath,
                            ItemProcessor<Student, Marksheet> processorListBath,
                            ItemWriter<Marksheet> itemWriterListBath
    ) {
    Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("List-load")
        .<Student, Marksheet>chunk(3)
        .reader(itemReaderListBath)
        .processor(processorListBath)
        .writer(itemWriterListBath)
        .build();
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("L-Load")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step)
        .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Emaill> itemReaderListBath() {
    return new ListItemReader();
    }
...
```

The ItemReader is described in a separate class List Item Reader

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ListItemReader implements ItemReader<Student> {
    @Autowired
    private CalService calService ;
    DataAtributes dataAtributes;
    ...
    @Override
    public Student read() {
    //Тут вызывается метод сервиса, который необходимо подменить
    dataAtributes = new DataAtributes(1,"test");
    Integer val = calService.addAttr(dataAtributes);
    ...  
    }
```

Here is the service itself

```java
@Service
public class CalService {
    public int addI(int input1) {
    return 0;
    }
    public Integer addAttr(DataAtributes attr) {
    return 0;
    }
}
```

in this service, the Job starts

```java
@Service
public class StartJob {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    Job jobDeveloper;
    public void launchJob() throws Exception {
    ...
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(jobDeveloper, params);
```

and the testing class itself

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class CaclServisTest {
    @Mock
    CalService calcService;
    @InjectMocks
    StartJob
    @Autowired
    StartJob startJob;

    @Test
    void add() {
    DataAtributes dataAtributes = new DataAtributes(1,"test");
    when(calcService.addAttr(dataAtributes)).thenReturn(57);
    startJob.launchJob();
    }
}
```

As a result, the native method is called, not the substituted one.
I do not understand what service should be installed @InjectMocks

Comment: 1. what is `getCalcService()` 2. What is `setCalc()`

Comment: i ' m sorry. Copied from the previous question incorrectly. Fixed the code

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Mock` field is not available for in Spring context.
In particular: `@Autowire StartJob startJob` uses `CalService` from Spring context, not your mock.

To replace a bean in Spring context, use `@MockBean` instead:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class CaclServisTest {
    @MockBean
    CalService calcService;

    @Autowired
    StartJob startJob;

    @Test
    void add() {
    DataAtributes dataAtributes = new DataAtributes(1,"test");
    when(calcService.addAttr(dataAtributes)).thenReturn(57);
    startJob.launchJob();
    }
}
```